# Path String Concatenation Question in C#

Tags: c#, path, string-concatenation

I want to output **D:\Learning\CS\Resource\Tutorial\C#LangTutorial**
But can't work. Compiler error *error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'StrPathHead*
Please give me some advice about how to correct my code or other better solution for my case. Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = "D:\\Learning\\CS\\Resource\\Book\\C#InDepth";
    int n = 0;

    string[] words = path.Split('\\');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {

            string StrPathHead;
            string StrPath;
            Console.WriteLine(word);

            if (word == "Resource")
            {
                StrPath = StrPathHead + word + "\\Tutorial\\C#LangTutorial"; 
            }
            else
            {
                StrPathHead += words[n++] + "\\";
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't initialised StrPath; you also declared in inner loop scope so will be replaced each time through loop, so won't currently work as you intend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Mitch Wheat, but you could solve your current problem initializating `StrPath`

`string StrPath = string.Empty;`

And as other people say, declare `StrPath` outside of the loop.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y7h161d%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> > The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. If the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been initialized, it generates CS0165.
> >
> > Use new to create an instance of an object or assign a value.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `StrPath` to the empty string ("") *and* declare it outside your loop.  You may also want to consider using a `StringBuilder` since `String`s in c# are immutable.

Comment: Thanks for giving `StringBuilder` suggeston to me.